# Swift Error "Type 'BookingDataModel' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'"

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, codable, jsonencoder

I wanted to make some part of my app offline as the my client requested it. I've been racking my brain on making my structure codable so that I can save the data to user defaults, but I always get this error

> Type 'BookingDataModel' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

Here is my BookingDataModal:

```
struct BookingDataModel: Codable {

    static var shared = BookingDataModel()

    var collaps = false
    var _id = ""
    var userId = ""
    var venderName = ""
    var created_at = ""
    var transaction_id = ""
    var payment_method = ""
    var updated_at = ""
    var booking_confirmed = false
    var booking_status = ""
    var payment_status = false
    var type = ""
    var isCanceledRequest: Bool?

    var flight: [FlightBookingDataModel]?
    var newFlight: (departure: [FlightBookingDataModel], return: [FlightBookingDataModel])?
    var event: HotelBookingDataModel?
    var hotel: NewHotelBookingDataModel?//HotelBookingDataModel?

    var isAxaPolicy = false
    var relationshipId = ""
    var passengers = [UsersModel]()
    var total = 0.0
    var tacCoinDiscount: Int?
    var couponDiscount: Int?
    var afterDiscountAmount: Int?

     func getBookingDataModel(arr: NSArray, type: String) -> [BookingDataModel] {
    // save data from API
    }
    }
```

At first I thought my other modals were not codable, so I made them all Codable, and it still would throw the same error
Here is the FlightBookingDataModal :

```
struct FlightBookingDataModel: Codable {

    static var shared = FlightBookingDataModel()

    var pnrData = PNRDataModel()
    var src_name = ""
    var dst_name = ""
    var srcCode = ""
    var dstCode = ""

    var atime_utc = String()
    var dtime_utc = String()
    var atime = String()
    var dtime = String()

    var flight_no = ""
    var checkin = ""
    var price = 0.0
    var airLineName = ""
    var eticket_link = ""
    var invoice = ""
    var isReturnFlight = false

    func getFlightBookigDataModel(dict: NSDictionary) -> [FlightBookingDataModel] {
    // Save data from API
    }
    }
```

PNR Modal :

```
class PNRDataModel: Codable  {
  var src = ""
  var dst = ""
  var iata = ""
  var pnr = ""
  }
```

HotelBookingDataModel :

```
struct HotelBookingDataModel: Codable {

    var cityName = ""
    var name = ""
    var address = ""
    var startOfServiceTime = ""
    var endOfServiceTime = ""
    var aetherReference = ""
    var provider = ""
    var reference = ""
    var price = 0.0
    var date = ""
    var reservationId = ""
    }
```

NewHotelBookingDataModel:

```
struct NewHotelBookingDataModel: Codable {
    var name = ""
    var address = ""
    var cityName = ""
    var price = 0.0
    var reference = ""
    var provider = "" //not found in new response
    var startOfServiceTime = ""
    var endOfServiceTime = ""
    var aetherReference = ""
    }
```

If anyone can give me any insights as why is this not working, that would help me a lot. I just want to save [BookingDataModal] offline for a limited time until the user comes back online.

Comment: There is `UsersModel`. It must conform to `Codable`, too. And when dealing with Codable don't assign default values to the properties (by the way it's bad practice anyway). And don't use `NS...` collection types in Swift at all.

Comment: Hi vadian, The UsersModal conforms to Codable too, I just forgot to post it in the details. I don't know where am I going wrong. And thanks for the tips, I'm kinda new to iOS developemnt and can really use some pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the error is the property `newFlight` in `BookingDataModel`.

`Codable` does not support tuples.